# NamedPipes deadlock in Message transferring mode

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ipc, named-pipes

Windows 7 platform, .NET 4.0 application using NamedPipes for same-machine IPC.
The pipe is created as follow:

```
   new NamedPipeServerStream(
        "test",
        PipeDirection.InOut,
        -1,
        PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
        PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
        128 * KB,
        128 * KB,
        _pipeSecurity)
        {
            ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message
        };
```

Client pipe has the same settings. After the pipe has got a client connected, they start sending large traffic two ways.
Reading data is done using BeginRead/EndRead, writing is done on a dedicated thread using blocking Write() call.
Everything works great while the message's size is less or equal to 128Kb.
If a message size is greater (say 256K), somethimes the server's async read does not respond. Client says it has written all data to the pipe, but server does not receive OnReadEnd callback (despite BeginRead is 100% invoked which is confirmed by debugger).
Note that the test does work for some amount of data sent two-ways, but suddenly blocks on a certain portion of data (message).

I checked Chromium project to see how they use namedpipes for IPC. They do support messages up to 128Mb (as per source code). The only differences: native (C++) vs .NET4 and Message mode vs Byte mode. Another OSS project "Named Pipes Wrapper" written in C# (see GitHub) claims it can handle messages up to 300Mb and it also uses Byte mode.

Summarizing, I suspect the problem is related to Message transmission mode. And IOCP fails to notify my server app that next portion arrived. Worth to mention also, the reading is done by blocks equal to Pipe's IO buffer size (128Kb in my case).

Question: have you ever noticed any issues related to using Message transmission mode when working with NamedPipes. No matter was that a .NET or native app.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, but one comment: Pipes do not have bugs. IOCP did not fail at anything. With very high likelihood the bug is in your code.

Comment: Not pipes maybe, but Framework glue layer or incorrect usage caused by this layer.. or whatever else. There are too many variables in this equation.

Comment: If you forget to add `PipeOptions.Asynchronous` it will certainly deadlock on `WriteAsync()`